# TypeScript generic rest parameters to union return type

Tags: typescript

Currently, TypeScript allows declaring dynamic generic parameters.

```js
function bind<U extends any[]>(...args: U);
```

But what if I want my function to return a union of argument types? Something like:

```js
function bind<U extends any[]>(...args: U): U1 | U2 | U3...;
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: How is `U` and `U1`/`U2`/`U3` related?

Comment: Depending on what arguments passed to the function args[] become arg[0]: U1, arg[1]: U2, arg[2]: U3. So I would return the union of passed arguments types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get a union of all arguments you can use `U[number]`:

```
function bind<U extends any[]>(...args: U): U[number] {
    return args[Math.round(Math.random()*(args.length - 1))]; // dummy implementation
}
let r = bind(1,"2", true) // number | string | boolean
console.log(r)
```

You can also get the type at a certain position, but since we don't know if the position will exist we need to use a conditional type;

```
type At<T extends any[], I extends number> = T extends Record<I, infer U> ? U : never;
function bind<U extends any[]>(...args: U): At<U, 0> {
    return args[Math.round(Math.random()*(args.length - 1))]; // dummy implementation
}
let r = bind(1,"2", true) // number
```